# Error when adding Oracle DB to ODBC connection

Tags: oracle, odbc

Hi everyone here,

I am pretty new to Oracle DB configurations as I have been using SAS and Microsoft SQL all this while.

What i want to do is to add Oracle DB to ODBC(64-bit) in a new server.

This is the scenario:

Server A:- Existing Application server that has Oracle configured in ODBC(64-bit)(Been using for the past 3 years, configured by other people).

Server DB:- The Database server

Server B:- Brand new server that i want to configure Oracle DB in ODBC(64-bit)(Brand new).

I copy every single details of the server information in Server A ODBC for the same Oracle DB and put it in Server B ODBC. I have both Server A and Server B remote connection side by side and do "Test Connection".

Server A can connect successfully. However, Server B is giving me this error:
[image]
SQLState=08004

This is my first time trying to configure for ODBC to Oracle DB. I have previously configured many Microsoft SQL DB without any issue. Do take note that i have not installed any Oracle driver or any necessary-tool needed for ODBC to link with Oracle as i do not know of any. Is there anything i have to install for this to work or any necessary settings need to be done before configuring it?

All this while for Microsoft SQL connection to ODBC, i just put in the DB credentials and voila.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you dit not define the DB alias in your `tnsnames.ora` file. The driver installation seems to be fine since you get an Oracle error.